# Sql запрос. Поиск строки

Tags: sql, postgresql, golang

```
        import "gopkg.in/pg.v3"
    type User struct {
    ID        int64
    Login     string
    Password  string
    IsActive  bool
    CreatedAt time.Time

    Database Databaseinfo
}

type DatabaseInfo struct {
    DB *pg.DB
}
    func (u *User) GetByName(login string) (*User, error) {
        _, err := u.Database.DB.QueryOne(u, `SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE login = ?;`, login)

        return u, err
    }
```

Правильно ли я понял, что запрос выгружает виртуальную таблицу, потом отсеивает строки не содержащие login.

Вопросы:

```
- Что означает символ  '?'
- Символ ';' означает конец строки
- Строка login передается в '...login = ?;'
```

Comment: "?" - означает параметр в параметризованном запросе. На сервере подготавливается запрос, называемый prepared statement. Такой запрос может содержать параметры. Потом на сервер передаются значения параметров и запрос выполняется с использованием этих значений вместо "?". Т.е. похоже на вызов функции с параметрами. ";" стандартный разделитель запросов sql. login, как уже сказал выше, передаётся на сервер в качестве значения первого (и единственного в данном случае) параметра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я с PostgreSQL не знаком, но в MySQL данный запрос, думаю, будет работать аналогично.

Символ `?` в данном случае является так называемым плейсхолдером. Плейсхолдеры нужны для защиты от SQL-инъекций, ну или как минимум для более удобной организации кода. На его место подставится значение переменной `login`, которую вы передали в качестве аргумента методу `u.Database.DB.QueryOne()`.

Символ `;` - это не конец строки, а конец SQL-выражения. В одной строке может быть несколько SQL-запросов и для того, чтобы разделить их, используется точка с запятой.

> Правильно ли я понял, что запрос выгружает виртуальную таблицу, потом отсеивает строки не содержащие login.

Данный запрос выгрузит все записи из таблицы `user`, где поле `login` соответствует значению переменной `login`.

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что "?" появились задолго до sql-инъекций. И предназначались для многократного выполнения одного и того же запроса, но с разными параметрами. А то что с помощью параметров можно избегать sql-инъекций, догадались почему-то относительно недавно. Ибо ранние версии функций php для работы с sql в принципе не имели понятия о запросах с параметрами. И для многих адептов php это и сейчас остаётся тайной.

Comment: Никогда не ставил точку с запятой в postgres-е. Может не так уж она ему обязательна, или драйвер автоматически подставляет? Не знаю, но основания усомниться в утверждении обязательности точки с запятой имеются.

Comment: @Sergey скорее всего вы и правы, я прочел это в доках к шестой версии СУБД. Удалю утверждение о точке с запятой.

Comment: В таблице user содержится столбец login, значит sql запрос будет искать совпадение по полям из этого столбца, так?

Comment: @Tarakan, не считая того, что вы ошиблись в терминологии, думаю, вы правильно всё поняли.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM user WHERE login = {login}";
```

Comment: В таблице user содержится столбец login, значит sql запрос будет искать совпадение по полям из этого столбца, так?